# Mostrar el dato máximo de una tabla SQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada **clientes**, con sus respectivos atributos: `nombre, DNI, ciudad`

```
CREATE TABLE clientes (
    nombre VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, 
    dni VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    ciudad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

**Mi idea es sacar qué ciudad tiene más clientes.**

Es decir:

```
CiudadA 4
CiudadB 9
CiudadC 2
```

Y como resultado me diga:

```
CiudadB 9
```

Sé extraer el contador de una ciudad, ¿pero cómo comparo con el resto?

```
SELECT count(ciudad) FROM clientes WHERE ciudad="CiudadA"
```

Comment: El valor de cada ciudad esta en una celda por separado o dentro de la misma que tiene el texto Ciudad?

Comment: Modifiqué la pregunta @BetaM Añadiendo cómo es la estructura de la tabla Clientes.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MySQL usas?

Comment: Utilizo SQL @BetaM

Comment: mmm no sé dónde se mira eso. Estoy usando MySQL en phpmyadmin.

Comment: @JoséBardales buscate algo que hacer de verdad que eres un acosador, pero si dejaré en este comentario muy en claro lo nocivo que es tu seguimiento a mi persona, de una vez respeta

Comment: Respetarse. Y José poco puedes hablar cuando tienes sólo 300 de reputación y tu perfil parece "bot". Cada respuesta es válida siempre y cuando sea respetable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es la ciudad con más clientes, lo que puedes hacer es agrupar por ciudad, contar os clientes de cada una, ordenar el conjunto de forma descendente y quedarte solo con el primer caso:

```
SELECT ciudad,
       COUNT(1) 
       FROM clientes 
       GROUP BY ciudad
       ORDER BY 2 DESC, ciudad
       LIMIT 1;
```

Comentarios:

- El `ORDER BY 2 DESC` odena los resultado por la segunda columna, el `COUNT()` de forma descendente
- La primer fila entonces debiera ser aquella ciudad con mayor cantidad de clientes.

Comment: ¿Por qué pones ORDER BY 2 DESC? ¿Por qué el "2"? El Limit1 intuyo que es para seleccionar el primero.

Comment: El `Order by 2 desc` está indicando que la consulta se ordene por la segunda columna (el count) de forma descendente, es decir, la primer fila será la ciudad con mayor cantidad de clientes, de ahí que luego usemos el limit, para quedarnos únicamente con esta fila.

Answer (score 2):

Imagino que quieres ver cuantos registros hay por ciudad, para ello debes contar el número de repeticiones de cada ciudad (tal como haces con el `COUNT`) y agruparlas por cada una de ellas (mediante `GROUP BY`).

```
SELECT ciudad, count(*) 
FROM clientes 
GROUP BY ciudad
```

También puedes obtener una lista más limitada, por ejemplo solo los que se repitan más de 10 veces, para ello tienes la cláusula `HAVING`

```
SELECT ciudad, count(*)
FROM clientes 
GROUP BY ciudad
HAVING count(*) > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes contar por cada ciudad y agruparlos de forma ascendente y solo tomar el mayor colocándole un limite.

```
SELECT ciudad, count(ciudad) 
FROM clientes 
GROUP BY ciudad ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```